# Последовательное добавление EditText в ScrollView при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, android-edittext, android-scrollview

Нужно сделать так чтобы при  нажатии на кнопку,  в ScrollView последовательно появлялись edit text. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете в ScrollView положить LinearLayout и добавлять в него програмно ваши EditText по нажатию на кнопку.

```
EditText myEditText = new EditText(context); 
myEditText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(..., ...)); // Здесь должны быть аргументы LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, либо же интовое (int) значение в пикселях
myLayout.addView(myEditText); //myLayout это ваш LinearLayout
```